# Backup Informix databases in AIX with Veeam

Tags: backup, aix, veeam

My production database is currently on an IBM server with AIX. We use Informix as our database software. We've migrated most of our physical assets to vSphere and back everything up with Veeam. We still have some Windows physical machines (need dedicated processors) that we use Veeam Endpoint Backup to the Veeam repository that is then replicated to a DR site and the cloud.

I'd like to do the same with Veeam, but their Linux version is beta and doesn't work on AIX. The architecture is different too. I'm considering exporting backups to a share on a proxy.

I'd like to find out if it's possible to get Veeam to upload non-Veeam backup files in the repository folder to the cloud?

Comment: "I'd like to find out if it's possible to get Veeam to upload non-Veeam backup files in the repository folder to the cloud?" <-- Why do you need Veeam for that purpose?!? You can use something like S3-Fuse. https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse

Comment: I know it sounds silly. We have a single solution (Veeam) and offsite backup with a Veeam partner. There are limitations to what can and can't be used and to sum it up, I just need to get Veeam to upload this data. I'm considering having the job save to a VM that has a NFS share mounted to the AIX servers and save the backups there. Then, backup the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a repo dedicated to Veeam for AIX systems. The databases save to a share and the Informix backups just replace themselves. Each keeps 3 restore points.

I hope Veeam comes up with a solution for AIX.